# Flow works in debug, not when live, looking for a Salesforce id

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow which runs when one of the fields on the object it links to has a specific value, which is an 18 character Salesforce id. It runs fine in debug, when never runs when I've activated it.

This is the sort of thing that was in the formula which has to be true for the flow to run:
{!$Record.xxx_related__c} = 'a111K000000cxxUAA'

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that although when I specify an 18 character Salesforce id it works in debug, the live one would only work when I put in the 15 character Salesforce id. So it had to be:
{!$Record.xxx_related__c} = 'a111K000000cxx'

Comment: IMHO hard coding an ID like this is a bad idea. You should find the ID of the required record via a query, and that will give you the form of ID needed to then check against... note that CASESAFEID can also help (gives 18 character ID which can then be trimmed to 15).

Comment: I could have queried for the name, but then if someone changes the name then the query breaks. Thanks for the tip for CASESAFEID

Comment: I'm with Phil here - use VR to prevent name change; or, use a shadow field on that object whose value is invariant